# How to store file from memory to a storage in Laravel5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, base64

I have a variable, which holds an image as a base64 string. How is it possible to put that file to a storage? I tried this:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk($disk_name)->putFileAs($dir_path, base64_decode($image_str), $file_name);
```

Unfortunately I get this error: `Call to a member function getRealPath() on string`

The reason is, that the second parameter of the `putFile` function should be an `Illuminate\Http\File` object, but I have no idea how to create one from a base64 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Storage::disk($disk_name)->put($dir_path . '/' . $file_name, base64_decode($image_str));
```

See the [Laravel Storage docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#storing-files).

The `put` method accepts the path of the file as the first parameter and the contents as the second parameter.

**Note:** if your `$dir_path` already includes a `/`, remove that from the function so there's not doubles.